# why am I getting a null value for this NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am getting a NSDictionary back form a web service that looks like this when logged:

```
NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dictionary);
```

Gives me:

```
dictionary: {
    BackOrderDate = "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM";
    Quantity = 15;
}
```

So then I try and get a date from that:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: [dictionary objectForKey:@"BackOrderDate"]];
```

Logging this gives me a (null) but I know my dictionary has a value:

```
NSLog(@"setting back order date:%@ %@",date, [dictionary objectForKey:@"BackOrderDate"]);
```

Gives me:

```
setting back order date:(null) 3/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Spending WAY to much time on this - what am I missing????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
```

Comment: unfortunately that makes no difference, still get (null)

Comment: Ok, that worked but what I really want is something like MM/dd/yyyy but that gives me a null - is that not a valid date format?

Comment: You should provide format like your string. In this way your string contains day, month, year and time. If you want to use format MM/dd/yyyy then your string should be @"1/1/0001" (`[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"BackOrderDate"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]`). But finally you retrieve NSDate object which will contain day, month, year, and time (time will be set to 00:00:00). So, i don't think that it's really helpful.